# My Bootstrap is not working, trying to include Mysql dropdown

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply Bootstrap to a Dynamic Dropdown.

My code doesn't work to match all other Menu Items that are not Mysql 
dropdown. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDcLx.png) is what it looks like.

My code:

```html
<li class = 'dropdown'>
    <a href = '#' class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-book' >
        <span class = 'caret'></span>
    </a>

    <select 
    onChange="window.location.href=this.value" class = 'dropdown-toggle' 
    data-toggle = 'dropdown'  >
        <ul class = 'dropdown-menu'>
            <option>Training </option>

<?php                                           

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM sessions where event_type = 'training' ORDER BY 
    pro_title ";

   $res = mysqli_query($con1, $sql);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)                                         
   {                                                 
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))                                        
       {                                         
           echo "<li><option value='mail/success.php?idx={$row['event_id']}'>{$row['pro_title']}</option></li>";                                         
       }                                 
    }
?>
        </ul>           
    </select>                               
<li>
```

Comment: Please edit your question properly.

Comment: echo "<li><option value='mail/success.php?idx={$row['event_id']}'>{$row['pro_title']}</option></li>";  ... Why "<li>" tag here ?

Comment: Thank you , 
Because the other non mysql menus are this way:
<li class = 'dropdown'  >
     <a class = 'dropdown-toggle' data-toggle = 'dropdown' href = '#' ><span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-book'></span> All Staff Meeting <span class = 'caret'></span></a>
     <ul class = 'dropdown-menu'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<select> elements must have <option> elements as children.

See [<select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) and [Native Form Widgets - DropDown Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/The_native_form_widgets#Drop-down_content)

In Bootstrap, however, DropDowns are made using either div elements or lists.

Based on your current code I assume you are using Bootstrap 3.x

Here is an example you can try:

```php
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
        Training <span class='caret'></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM sessions where event_type = 'training' ORDER BY pro_title ";

        $res = mysqli_query($con1, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                echo "<li><a href='mail/success.php?idx={$row['event_id']}'>{$row['pro_title']}</a></li>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
<li>
```

To learn more about the structure I encourage you to check out the following links (Bootstrap 3.x):

- [Bootstrap - Pills with dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#pills-with-dropdowns)
- [Bootstrap - Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#dropdowns)

**Update**

The `<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value"> does the same as if you would click on the links in the dropdown <a href="somelink">text</a>`.

Nevertheless, you can do that when clicking on the item like so:

Try this code for echoing the list items:

```php
echo "<li><a onclick='window.location.href=\"mail/success.php?idx={$row['event_id']}\">{$row['pro_title']}</a></li>";
```

Comment: Thank you So Much that works but menus now are not triggering success.php?idx
There is  onChange="window.location.href=this.value" missing I thing :-) 
Anyway to include that ?
Thank you so much in advance .
Ed-

Comment: I've added an update section to my post. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you Attila, It works fine now, except when I for instance dropdown, and select Tarining#1, I get results, admin/sessions.php?idx=1
Onn the same page (admin/sessions.php?idx=1), I click on dropdown to select another item, but the Dropdown is not responding... I have to go always to ho home where it seems forking fine as there is not ?idx at the end of the URL, any idea please ?
Many thanks @Attila.

Comment: UPDATE :
It's working all of a sudden now :-) interesting !
Thank you All for your Help here .. Thank you @Attila.